# Adding a new team project to Team Foundation Server 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-2015

I am trying to set up Team Foundation Server for my official visual studio projects, and we have set up TFS 2015 - Basic Server setup.

I have been working with Visual Studio 2012 in my development machine and trying to connect to the TFS and add projects to it.

When I go to File -> New Team Project, I got an error saying 'TF0172: You are trying to create a team project either without required permissions or with an older version of Team Explorer. Contact your project administrator to check your permissions or to determine how to upgrade Team Explorer'.

I have admin rights in the TFS server as well as in the development machine so the error machine does not look like it is a permission issue.

So trying to see if VS2012 is compatible with TFS 2015, or is it possible to make both compatible?
I have also updated my Visual Studio 2012 with the update 5.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a team project requires a matching version of Visual Studio. So, to create a team project in TFS 2015, you need Visual Studio (or Team Explorer) 2015.